# How to remove non-alphabetical characters from a string?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a way to remove characters from any string that are not alphabetical characters.

I am basically just using Replace for every non-Alphabetical character. This method would take forever.

I guess I could make an array (I think) but that would still take quite a while. Is there any simple solution?

```
Dim wordy As String = textBox.Text.ToUpper.Replace(".", "").Replace("!", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("'", "").Replace("?", "") _
        .Replace(",", "").Replace("-", "")
```

Comment: So sorry, wrong language...oops. Try my answer below.

Comment: You could just use a masked textbox that would allow only numeric input based on the mask...

Answer (score 8):

The following lines of code should help.

```
MsgBox(Regex.Replace(s, "[^a-zA-Z ]", ""))
```

This will keep only upper/lowercase A-Z as well as spaces.

Your example,

```
Dim wordy As String = textBox.Text.ToUpper.Regex.Replace(s, "[^a-zA-Z ]", "")
```

You could also just use a **MaskedTextBox** that would allow only numeric input based on the mask.

Comment: Not tested, but should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

This will remove all characters except A-Z in lower and upper case, as well as spaces.  If you want spaces to be removed, remove the space from the end of the regular expression.

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("[^a-zA-Z ]")
Dim wordy As String = rgx.Replace(textBox.Text,"")
```