# Get only letters from string vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net

i want to get only letters from string.
eg. 
Lets say the string is this :123abc456d
I want to get: abcd
Looking for something like this but for letters in a string:

```
Dim mytext As String = "123a123"
Dim myChars() As Char = mytext.ToCharArray()
For Each ch As Char In myChars
     If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
          MessageBox.Show(ch)
     End If
Next
```

Thanks

Comment: See [How to remove non-alphabetical characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463134/how-to-remove-non-alphabetical-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
Dim mytext As String = "123a123"
Dim RemoveChars As String = "0123456789" 'These are the chars that you want to remove from your mytext string
Dim FinalResult As String
Dim myChars() As Char = mytext.ToCharArray()
For Each ch As Char In myChars
    If Not RemoveChars.Contains(ch) Then
        FinalResult &= ch
    End If
Next
MsgBox(FinalResult)
```

---

**OR :**

```
Dim mytext As String = "1d23ad123d"
Dim myChars() As Char = mytext.ToCharArray()
Dim FinalResult As String
For Each ch As Char In myChars
    If Not Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
        FinalResult &= ch
    End If
Next
MsgBox(FinalResult)
```

Both will give you the same result.

**Hope that helped you :)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex to solve this problem. This regex basically says anything that is not in this class, the class being letters in the alphabet then remove by replacing it with nothing.

```
Dim mytext As String = "123a123"
Dim Result as String = Regex.Replace(myText, "[^a-zA-Z]", "")
Dim myChars() As Char = Result.ToCharArray()
For Each ch As Char In myChars
  If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
      MessageBox.Show(ch)
  End If
Next
```

Make sure you have this at the top of your code `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LINQ one liner:

```
Debug.Print(String.Concat("123abc456d".Where(AddressOf Char.IsLetter)))
```

Result: `abcd`.

Here, `.Where(AddressOf Char.IsLetter)` treats the string as a list of chars, and only keeps letters in the list. Then, `String.Concat` re-builds the string out of the char list by concatenating the chars.